Using the Boost library to include a C++ program in python with Python.h, bjam not found
I have code in C++ that performs multiple mathematical equations. When doing it with Python, it takes a long time (about 5 minutes), and when running it in C++, it takes about 10 seconds. I want to have Python use the C++ functions. I read that with the Boost.Python library, this task could be done, but I am having problems when compiling the C++ program.
The first error I encounter is that, after including the boost/python library as follows:
#include <boost/python.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

I get the following error:
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE_INIT namespace “boost::python::detail” has no “init_module” member.

This is the tutorial link that i use Boost.Python Tutorial
I find the documentation very confusing. What I have tried so far is to use Visual Studio 2022, start a new project and select a dll file. When I include <boost/python.hpp> I don't get any error, but when I put the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext) line I get the error mentioned above.
=========================== EDIT ===========================
In the Boost.python tutorial, I tried to run the example using bjam but it does not recognize it as an internal or external command in cmd, I looked for a way to install it but according to what I found, there should be an executable called bjam in the base folder of boost, I only found a file called Jamroot but I don't know what to do with it.
Apart from this, in the example folder it says that it should have a list of files:

hello.cpp
hello.py
Jamroot

But instead of the jamroot file, there is only a file called Jamfile, in which the following content is found:
Jamfile
import python ;

project tutorial
  : requirements
    <location>.
    ;

python-extension hello_ext : hello.cpp ;

run-test hello : hello_ext hello.py ;

alias test : hello ;
explicit test ;

hello.cpp
#include <boost/python/module.hpp>
#include <boost/python/def.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
   return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}

hello.py
import hello_ext
print(hello_ext.greet())

I really started using visual studio out of ignorance, but now that I've reached this point, I don't understand how to install bjam or how to configure the jamroot file specified in the tutorial, nor do I understand what to do with that jamfile.
And I necessarily have to use c++, it is not an option to migrate all the code to pure python since it was tried before and did not meet the expected time.

"when I include <boost/python.h>" -- Your code includes <boost/python.hpp> not <boost/python.h>. I think this is just sloppiness in your text (and I don't think this is the cause of your problem), but please double-check and correct your question (including the title).

Please include the full error message. In particular, it's very relevant where the error occurs and MSVC also includes an error code (Cxxxx or LNKyyyy) which server as key for research.

From the second page of the tutorial to which you linked: "Experience shows that 90% of the 'I can't build Boost.Python' problems come from people who had to use a different tool [than bjam]." Are you sure you want to use Visual Studio instead of bjam?

Before taking this route, have you investigated whether numpy or scipy could run your equations?  Both of those are standard modules that are mathematics-heavy and are implemented in C or Fortran for speed.

Boost can be heavy and finicky to set up. I recommend trying pybind11 instead.

@JaMiT it actually sounds like conflict of two different boost setups. Usually if setup wasn't finished that particular header would end with missing pyconfig.h header. Thing is Vs is very popiular tool  for offline\air-gapped use in enterprise environment. But nearly every OSS library is designed with "you need Internet access to install this" way to setup, which result sin attepts to trying undocumented workarounds.

@Swift-FridayPie I didn't say that VS could not be used. I asked for confirmation that this was an intentional choice (and not merely a case of "Oops, there's a second page to the tutorial that tells me how to build things?" but I wasn't going to call that out explicitly).

I have just updated the question trying to solve all the doubts mentioned in the comments.

Ok, it seems that what used to be known as bjam is now b2, I don't see this in the documentation, but I still don't know how to compile the example using b2.
